# azure Devops pipeline setup for on premises data Gateway

Tags: azure-devops, data-gateway

I am trying to setup oracle data gateway using Azure Devops pipeline, but i didn't found any document. Please help me on this. please guide me how to setup oracle data gateway using azure devops pipeline and please send me if you have any documents.

Answer (score 0):

> how to setup oracle data gateway using azure devops pipeline and please send me if you have any documents.

I am afraid there is no such way to setup oracle data gateway using azure devops pipeline.

First, to setup oracle data gateway, we need to download and run the gateway installer on a local computer. But there is such command line to download and run the gateway installer.

Secondly, there is no such extension for installing oracle data gateway in the [Azure devops Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops).

So, there is no such way to setup oracle data gateway using azure devops pipeline.

Comment: As per my requirement i didn't get solution but you said don't have any data gateway pipeline setup as of now.  Manual setup i know the procedure but i need pipeline setup for data gateway.

Comment: how to using powershell to setup data gateway. if you have any documents or steps so please provide me.

Comment: @MohammadHafiz, I am not an expert in powershell and data gateways, and I cannot provide you with professional guidance. I can only answer your questions from the perspective of Azure devops. If you want to use powershell to setup data gateway, you could update the tags in your question.